# Searching for area of specific city in country

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am searching for area of GCC but I am not able to get any dependency city related area in google search even thought I found few link I added here.

http://www.geonames.org/export/

https://geonames.nga.mil/namesgaz/

https://www.worldcitiesdatabase.com/  (this only showing up to cities not area)

Those link were there but this is not populated related area of city. It return all area of region instead of city base. Even we can able to buy paid service of Country/city and complete related area.

I am seeking any standard idea or source so that I can forward and complete my task.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Y no one providing answer for this question i was waiting for this more then 2 days . So this case we cannot able to get area of city from any where..?

Comment: Good advice here [about whether questions will/must be answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396944).